# How to prevent user registration

Tags: 7, users

I'm getting a couple of user registrations on my personal website (presumably from bots or people trying to hack my site). How do I disable new user registration entirely?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change the setting 'Who can register accounts?' to 'Administrators only' at http://yoursite.com/admin/config/people/accounts

Comment: That was so obvious... I must have been brain dead when I asked this! Thanks

Comment: If automated, use drush: drush vset user_register 0

Answer (score 3):

Go to admin/config/people/accounts and check the box that says Administrators only under **Who can register accounts?**