# How to let administrators AND anonymous users create new accounts?

Tags: users

I need to let anonymous users create his/her own accounts. But also I wish to create accounts when logged in as administrator. Is it possible such configuration? In admin/config/people/accounts is not possible, it just let you choose between exclusive options...

Comment: Duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/how-to-prevent-user-registration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent user registration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16000/how-to-prevent-user-registration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create users as an administrator by going to *admin/people/create*.

So, in *admin/config/people/accounts*, in the **Who can register accounts?** you can choose *Visitors* and you will be good to go.

Comment: Great! Thank you. And what about if I want a user (with some specific role) to create new accounts?

Comment: Sure. You can assign that permission to any role. Just go to *admin/people/permissions* and check the "Administer users" checkbox for the role you want to grant that permission.